# Laravel: Read environment variables from Apache config versus .env file

Tags: php, laravel, apache, laravel-8

I've removed my environment variables from my `.env` file and moved them to my Apache config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName example.com
       DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public

       SetEnv APP_NAME=Example
       SetEnv APP_ENV=production

       <Directory /var/www/html>
              Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
              AllowOverride All
       </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I've also checked to make sure `env_module` is enabled and restarted Apache.

The environment variables are no longer being recognized. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You should not use .env from Apache config rather than .env from project root because it is an eco-friendly process to get constant and secure credentials from project root .env. It will cause a big problem during changes in .env from Apache because for reflection of changes you need to restart the server again and on the production-based system it will affect all your uses and print a bad impression. So please you .env from root project rather than Apache config.